# Numpy - Array dot product depending on order of input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do a dot product and if I put a transposed array as the first parameter I get the correct answer (a single value) since it is essentially its a sum of products `sum(a*b)`. But if I put the transposed array as the second parameter it gives me a 2x2 array. Why?

```
a = np.array([[1],[2]])

b = np.array([[3],[4]])

np.dot(a,b.T)
Out[208]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])

np.dot(a.T,b)
Out[209]: array([[11]])

np.dot(b.T, a)
Out[210]: array([[11]])
```

Comment: `dot` is only an inner product for 1D input. For 2D input, it's matrix multiplication.

Comment: Did either of the answers provided answer your question?

Comment: @RyanStout Sorry about that, Got caught up with work and didn't check my stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply a k by 1 matrix (a vector) with a 1 by k matrix, you get a k by k matrix.
If you multiply a 1 by k matrix with a k by 1 matrix, you get a 1 by 1 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

`np.dot` does not calculate the dot product of multiple arrays. It calculates the matrix multiplication of two `ndarray`s.

You can calculate the dot product of two vectors with `np.dot` because the dot product of vectors `a` and `b` is simply `a^T * b`. However, as with regular vectors, `a^T * b` and `b * a^T` result in two very different answers. The former calculates the dot product of the vectors, while the latter calculates the product of `b` and `a^T`.

Comment: "dot product of vectors a and b is simply a * b^T" isn't true. the dot product is a^T * b when a and b are both column vectors as in the question here

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice my typo there.

Comment: In `numpy` we have to be careful when talking about vectors and transpose.  With a 1d vector, transpose does nothing.  The OP has column vectors (n,1), for which `.T` does make a difference.